# how does Heroku's firewall configuration apply to my instance

Tags: firewall

what ports are open to our environment? what "Certain types of attacks"  are we protected from? as Heroku doesn't allow our instance to have customized firewall settings

went to knowledgebase. understand the purpose but details of how wer not provided